# How can I visualize the likelihood in Bayesian model averaging?

Tags: bayesian

I have a question regarding Bayesian model averaging (BMA). Let M be a set of models 1...K. D are the data. Then the posterior probability of the Kth model has a following form:

$$
P(M_{K}|D) = \frac{P(D|M_{K}) \cdot P(M_{K})}{P(D)}
$$

I dont understand, how can I imagine the likelihood $P(D|M_{K})$. I know that the likelihood can be expressed as

$$
P(D|M_{K}) = \int P(D| \theta_{K} ; M_{K}) \cdot P( \theta_{K} | M_{K}) d \theta_{K}
$$

where $\theta$ is the set of models parameters. I understand this as an intersect of the likelihood of the data and the K-th model. Like this:

[image]
Whre X-axis stands for data points from D and Y-axis is the likelihood.

Am I correct? Thanks a lot for explaining.

Comment: @Xi'an I mean visualize. In other words, do I understand the likelihood correctly (based on my picture) ?

Comment: @Xi'an yes, x-axis represents the data points from D

Comment: The graphical representation is not adequate, if only because $P(M_K)$ does not depend on the data $D$.

Comment: @Xi'an Yes, but $P(D|M_{K})$  is "how would data look like if the $M_{K}$ is true" ?

Comment: I don't see anything in the formulas that corresponds to the shaded region in the plot.  Are you perhaps equating *multiplication* with "intersection"?  Or maybe *conditional probability* with intersection?

Comment: @whuber thanks for your answer. Now I see your point. Is there any other way how to visualize $P(D|M_{K})$, or not?

Comment: You can separately visualize the prior and the posterior densities (either by using the PDFs if you have a closed form, e.g., if you have conjugate priors; or by sampling). And of course you can plot them on the same coordinate grid. This is just plotting two densities, there is nothing specifically *Bayesian* about it. There is no point to the intersection of the two, though.